# Why does recorded footage and photos get framed wider when you use Live View in the Canon 1300D?

Tags: canon, composition, live-view, rear-lcd

[I have been reading the review of the Canon EOS 1300D by *The Digital Picture* and I came across this](https://www.the-digital-picture.com/Reviews/Canon-EOS-Rebel-T6.aspx)

> As with the T5, the T6 image details in the color block comparisons
>   are very slightly smaller than those from some of the other 18
>   megapixel DSLR samples. This is because the T6's Live View display
>   does not provide quite a 100% view, causing the test target to be
>   framed slightly wider than other models.

What exactly being "widened" mean? Why does that happen?

Comment: Substitute "displayed stretch to fill" for "framed slightly wider."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't actually the live feed that gets widened, but the resulting photo:

It appears that the live view does not display the full frame as recorded, just as the viewfinder only provides 95% coverage. Why LV is designed like this, I cannot say.

This means that, when they shot their test chart so it filled the LV, the actual photo recorded a bit more on the sides. This is what they mean by "framed slightly wider".

As a result, the blocks of the chart are a bit smaller in the photo as with a different camera with the same MP which framed the target narrower.

Answer (score -1):

The rear LCD appears to have a resolution of 1280 x 720 (921600) pixels, which is smaller than a HD video of 1920 x 1080 pixels, meaning it can't display the video at full size. The video must be reduced to be shown on the monitor. The simplest way to do this is to simply crop the video, which means information on the edges will not be seen. The recorded video will be wider than what is seen on the monitor.

Comment: 1920 x 1080 cropped to 1280 xv720 would be described as more than "slightly" croped!

Comment: They're both 'video' sizes though, in effect 1080p & 720p, both 16:9.

Comment: This answer, though accepted, is factually wrong. the Q isn't even about video.

Comment: @ths Live View means showing a video stream from the sensor.

Comment: Also, 1920×1080 and 1280×720 are both exactly the same aspect ratio, so this doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @mattdm it's not the aspect ratio but the absolute pixel count that matters. I make an assumption that the camera circuitry is optimized to make a standard HD video output, which is the only reason I bring it up.

Comment: Seems unlikely. Most rear LCD screens don't match that. The 1300D has a 4:3 rear LCD screen with "920,000 dots" — which means it's 640×480 actual pixels. Obviously much lower resolution that either 1080p or 720p.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, the camera can record in  1080p, 720p, or VGA (640×480, same as the rear LCD). It's possible that the 640×480 video is from the same reduced frame as the live view mode, so perhaps you're on to something there.

Comment: @mattdm I tried almost everything to find the actual resolution of the rear panel LCD, finally found a reference saying it was 921600 pixels which was conveniently 1280*720. How did you get 640*480?

Comment: For whatever awful marketing reason, camera rear LCD screens (and EVFs, for that matter) are marketed with their resolution in "dots", which is sub-pixels. Three sub-pixels makes an actual color pixel. 640×480×3 = 921,600.

Comment: It's probably more than coincidence that 1280×720 is exactly 3× the number of pixels as VGA, but I suppose that's a topic for [retrocomputing.se] or similar.